# Setting up Android Studio to work offline

Tags: android, android-studio, offline, offline-caching

I do job in an area where there is no internet connection. I wanted to develop Android apps using Android Studio, but for the Gradle build it needs an internet connection. Is there a way in which I can completely setup Android Studio to work offline?

I have tried many answers on Stack Overflow but none worked. Else, suggest me some other ways to make Android apps completely offline.

Answer (score 5):

Before moving to area where you don't have an internet connection, sync project to download all dependencies. Next gradle providing options, **Offline work**.

*File* -> *Settings* -> *Build, Execution, Deployment* -> *Gradle* and turn on option Offline Work. That is it.

Comment: But what if I wanted to create a program their.can i download all dependencies in advance?

Comment: I don't see offline work option under as instructed in newer version of 2023, could anyone point where it is (if still available anyway)?